# Клиент не может распарсить дату (android 2.3)

Tags: дата, android, httpclient

Здравствуйте, форумчане.

Возникла такая проблема на 2.3 версии андроида:

Выполняю авторизацию, мне от неё приходит в куках время, дальше я уже с этим клиентом тогда могу другие операции выполнять.

Сначала клиент не мог распарсить дату, поэтому пришлось поставить в параметры вот такой вот шаблон (`"EEE, dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss 'UTC'"`).

Но в 2.3 всё опять же осталась та ошибка, такое ощущение либо ему пофиг на эти параметры, либо в 2.3 версии шаблон нужен немного другой.

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: может быть по той причине, что MMM - это название месяца (трехбуквенное), а оно сильно зависит от локали? И если строка приходит на английском, а локаль на телефоне русская, то работать скорее всего не будет.

Answer (score 1):

Дело в локализации. При вызове функции парсинга, ему необходимо передать локализацию. Можете передать default локализацию

> ```
> Date d = new Date(); 
> DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss
> ```
>
> yyyy/MM/dd"); 
>     df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EAT"));
>
> ```
> System.out.println(df.format(d));
> ```

Comment: А я что не знаю где эту локаль проставить...
Я делаю просто так:

BasicHttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
  String[] patternsArray = new String[2];
  patternsArray[0] = "EEE, dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss 'UTC'";
  patternsArray[1] = "E, dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss 'UTC'";

  params.setParameter(CookieSpecPNames.DATE_PATTERNS, patternsArray);


Есть у меня ещё один класс , я там переопредляю парсер домена , чтобы он домен всегда был одинаков. Так же я переопределил для экспайресов  , но в аргументы уже приходить не та дата , а часть её , а точнее :
не вся дата а часть её до пробела, например "Thu"

Comment: ап ап ап ап

Comment: Что то вообще никак не получается , всё время приходит в парсер только часть даты которая до первого пробела...

главное после наверное уже с 3 версии андроида всё работает  а в 2.3 нет , почему так?